# Honda radio not working

Tags: honda, accord, audio

I have a 1995 Honda accord and I was driving one day when my radio just went blank. Then it says code on it. So I entered the code and right as I enter the last number the radio makes a beep then the radio goes blank and I can't do anything. No sound nothing on the screen and none of the buttons do anything. I have tried a few times to pull the fuse and put it back in and the same thing keeps happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: How long did you leave the fuse out? If for only a few seconds, try leaving it out for a few minutes. I take it you already have the security code, so that is good. If this doesn't work, you may need to pull it from the harness (out of the dash) for a few minutes, then try it again. I don't know how the security end of things go for Honda radios, so am leaving this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Take two butter knives and shove them in gap at the top of your radio about an inch or two from the sides. It should push the clips in and it will slide right out. Sometimes the cables come out in the back.